# AltChunk corrupts rich text content control

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, openxml

I used `AltChunk` object to copy data from a `docx` file to a rich text content control in another file. The copy works fine. But now the content control cannot be cast into a `SdtElement` in OpenXml nor to a `ContentControl` in VSTO.

This is the code I used

```
SdtElement sdtElement = destinationdocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(b => b.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>() != null).FirstOrDefault();
string altChunkId = "AltChunkId" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = destinationdocument.MainDocumentPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImport    PartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);
chunk.FeedData(File.Open("sourceFile", FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
sdtElement.RemoveAllChildren();
sdtElement.Append(altChunk);
```

the first time the code works fine. But at the second run the first line throws an unable to cast exception. The same problem occurs while using VSTO at the client side the `ContentControl` object cannot hold the content control in which the `AltChunk` was inserted. Somehow this procedure corrupts the rich text content control.

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Or is there a better alternative?

Comment: It helps to get more focused answers if you include the exception details in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>()` returns `IEnumerable<SdtElement>` and you are assiging it to `SdtElemtnt`. Try using `var` or the actual return type.

**Update:**

Your code is a working one. What you are doing wrong is this line `sdtElement.RemoveAllChildren();`

An sdt element (Content control) contains other elements like  sdtPr (content control properties), sdtContent (the actual content inside the content control) etc. as in the below eg.

```
 <w:sdt>
    <w:sdtPr>
        ...
    </w:sdtPr>
    <w:sdtContent>
      ....
    </w:sdtContent>
  </w:sdt>
```

What your `sdtElement.RemoveAllChildren();` doing is to delete everything inside the sdt element and replacing them as:

```
<w:sdt>
   <w:altChunk r:id="AltChunkIdffebf242-30b3-4905-bf39-fc0077be9474" />
</w:sdt>
```

Which is making your program to throw exception on secondrun as in line `destinationdocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(b => b.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>() != null).FirstOrDefault();` your replaced document sdt element has no `SdtProperties` and also no `Tag` or `sdtContent`.

To workaround this problem try inserting your altchunk block into the content control content element (`sdtContent`) instead of the sdt element directly as below:

```
using (
    FileStream fileStream = File.Open("file.docx",
                                        FileMode.Open))
{
    chunk.FeedData(fileStream);
    AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
    altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
    //sdtElement.RemoveAllChildren();
    sdtElement.Elements<SdtContentBlock>().FirstOrDefault().Append(altChunk); // This is going to add to the existing content.
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just pasted a part of the code. It has LINQ extension methods which cast it for me. It worked fine previously. The problem occurs in VSTO too. The problem is identified. The content control is somehow corrupt.

Comment: Your code is not showing what the sdtElement is and where you are inserting the altchunk in the document. Could you please update your question to include these details.