# Convert AltChunks to paragraphs and runs

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have implemented a mechanism in which I copy complete documents to a content control using an `AltChunk`. This implementation allows a user to change data frequently. When these changes are triggered I create yet another `AltChunk` to replace the previous contents. However the older chunk still contributes to the file size and it increases until the file is manually opened and saved in `WinWord.Exe`

Scenario : I tried to insert 10 images using `AltChunk` which increased the file size from 18K to 2187K. Next I tried to replace the 10 images with a plain small string. The document is updated with the new content but the size remained 2187K. And then when I opened the file manually in `WinWord.Exe` and saved it, the size dropped back to 19K. On research I found that Word application converts the `AltChunk` to Paragraphs and Runs.

My question : Can I mimic this Word Application behavior in `Open Xml`?

Please find this allied post to better understand what am I doing 
[AltChunk corrupts rich text content control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831570/altchunk-corrupts-rich-text-content-control/14831662#comment20780962_14831662)

Comment: Could you please post your code snippet that deletes the image?

Comment: You could delete the unused AlternativeFormatInputParts.

Comment: Even if you use a single AltChunk, it embeds a complete document inside your document. Thats expensive. Very expensive